# Formula to remove time, symbols/punctuation, standardize date to d/m/yyyy and remove duplicates from results

Tags: google-sheets

I need a formula to turn this

**[21:33, 1/8/2021] Palash: 15minlunch**

into

**1/8/2021 Palash 15mins lunch**

1. Array formula, dynamically insert row when there data
2. To remove time and  [ ] , : from string
3. To remove unnecessary zeros from month and day (d/m/yyyy)
4. To standardize all meal breaks status (with bad spellings, missing space,missing 's', wrong capitalization etc) to, No lunch, No dinner, 15mins dinner, 30mins lunch, 15mins lunch, 45mins lunch. (If possible)
5. Remove entries with exact same date, Name, and Status

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s93rWk0YljIKWkZ0Wpi7I3PPIbfVVEnpH3PmaGToN-c/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried regextract but the results always vary due to the irregular way the status is keyed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in row 3:

```
=arrayformula(unique(if(A3:A<>"",regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexextract(A3:A,",\ (.*)"),"[\]\:]",),"(\d)(min)(s)?(.*)","$1mins $4"),"\ min","min"),"Lunch","lunch"),"Dinner","dinner"),"\ {2,}","\ "),"(0)?(\d\/)","$2"),)))
```

Or to split them:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(unique(if(A3:A<>"",regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexextract(A3:A,",\ (.*)"),"[\]\:]",),"(\d)(min)(s)?(.*)","$1mins $4"),"\ min","min"),"Lunch","lunch"),"Dinner","dinner"),"\ {2,}","\ "),"(0)?(\d\/)","$2"),)),"(.*)\ ([\dN].*)"),))
```

Comment: Thank you @Aresvik,  the solution is working for most parts except that it cannot turn '15 mins lunch' into '15mins lunch'. The main purpose for them to be exact is for the unique function to pick off the duplicate. I appreciate the solution as it is if it is not possible.

Comment: Very very good. Thank you so much @Aresvik.

Comment: A problem that I didn't spot earlier. The formula wrongly format the date and month. 2/8/2021 = 2nd August 2021, but it returns, 8th Febuary 2021,

Comment: OK, I should be able to look at that later today or tomorrow. Can you indicate on your sheet where the issue is? The formula gets text, it doesn't do any formatting. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s93rWk0YljIKWkZ0Wpi7I3PPIbfVVEnpH3PmaGToN-c/edit?usp=sharing